# How cani write Linq Query for getting Record over multipul times

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Here I create one class `FatClass`:

```
 public class Ems_UserFat_Tab
 {
    public string Hr_Email { get; set; }

    public string BuHead_Email { get; set; }
```

My table is

```
Id   Email            RoleId  
1    abc@gmail.com     2             
2    lmn@gmail.com     3
```

Linq Query as

```
var x = from n in db.EMS_USER_MASTER
        where n.ROLE_ID == 2 || n.ROLE_ID==3
        select new Ems_UserFat_Tab
        {
            Hr_Email = n.EMAIL,
            BuHead_Email=n.EMAIL
        };
```

Here how can I differentiate `ROLE_ID=2` email and  `ROLE_ID=3` email in this query

Comment: Can you show the definition of `EMS_USER_MASTER`?

Comment: @Ofiris This is my table Name In this Table i Have Emails and RoleId

Comment: Something like `EMS_USER_MASTER.Where(x => x.ROLE_ID == 2 || x.ROLE_ID == 3).GroupBy(x => x.RoleID)` ?

Comment: Why can't you just take everything to local variable and separate them according to ur needs.

Comment: @Naruto Could u please Explain It ?

Comment: @lucky125111 Could u please mention How can i write Group by using Role

Comment: @randostina: gave the exact same answer which im referring to. You can just extra lazy loading part to it. To  make it more efficient

Comment: @JeamsAndernson what do you mean?

Comment: @lucky125111 I did nt understand what is Jorge

Comment: @JeamsAndernson Jorge from your nick

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void OnNext()
 {
     var x = list.Where(ro => ro.roleID = 2 && ro.roleID = 3)
                 .Select(ro => new CacheObject
                     {
                         Hr_Email = ro.EMAIL,
                         BuHead_Email=ro.EMAIL
                     });
 }
```

You have to store those values in Cache or to evoke them from DB ,which will be your object like in the example new CacheObject. Try to do it like this and debug it.

Comment: Im getting Error at list.Where   Error as Cant use local local varibale

Comment: Please, read this first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations